# Unity Line Renderer Not Straight

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am messing around with unity's Line Renderer and I can not seem to see why the following issue is occurring.

[image]

As you can see its not straight for some reason.

[image: Picture of problem]

Here are all my settings for the line renderer. 
Another very strange thing I am seeing is if I set Element 2's X to 10 so that its in the same X position as Element 1 the entire line just disappears. If anyone has any ideas on that as well it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

## This is due to how Line Renderers work.

Lines are a dynamically created mesh that uses quads to display the "line." As such, its susceptible to all sorts of problems that comes with generating meshes at runtime.

[image: Quads]

Notice how the vertical stroke's two triangles (in cyan) properly render two triangles to make a rectangle, but the two in green do not. This is because at that corner, the mesh got turned up side down.

This was likely due to either the cube changing direction (e.g. is started facing left but the first move was to the right) or flipping upside down entirely, causing a twist in the mesh. The top "edge" in green is equivalent to the diagonal edge in the cyan quad.

The only way to "fix" this is to use smaller chunks. Rather than adding a new point every time the cube changes direction, add new points every frame, every ten frames, or every 0.5 units or similar.